# ToString() format is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a strange problem.  We use Dutch and French lanuage on our site (nl-NL /  fr-FR)

I'm binding to a gridview and the strange thing is, the numeric value-saparator (dot) is not displaying well for French (fr-FR)

ASP.NET

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbla_min_10 = new Label();
    lbla_min_10 = e.Row.FindControl("lbla_min_10") as Label;
    lbla_min_10.Text = ((int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "a_min_10")).ToString("#,#.###");
    //....
}
```

e.g. DB value is 24369
in Dutch it displays  24.369  and

in French it displays 24 369    -> there is no DOT separator, but an empty space.

I looked at the view source and the code looks the same except theres is a  (dot) in NL and (space) in FR.....

Does someone have any idea?

why does it work for Dutch (nl-NL) fine and not for French (fr-FR)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using "nl-BE" and "fr-BE". They use the same formatting when it comes to numbers.

```
String.Format("{0:##,###}", 12345); // nl-NL: 12.345
String.Format("{0:##,###}", 12345); // fr-FR: 12 345
String.Format("{0:##,###}", 12345); // nl-BE: 12.345
String.Format("{0:##,###}", 12345); // fr-BE: 12.345
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Fr Culture' there is no separator between 1000's and 100's. So if you write 10.000 in dutch you can write 10 000 in french..
Why is it a problem?

Comment: thanks Ban.... is there any documentation... what is what? I mean FR is has space separator and NL has . separator... So I can have an overview?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark Here you can see an explanation and in the middle of the page a list of countries using space, point or coma for a separator.. It is just due to history and Habits.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the french denote thousands. with a space. The dutch use a .(full stop), the Engish use a , (comma).

So the regional formatting is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it behaves correctly. The problem is, what you actually used is grouping (thousands) separator. If you want it to be formatted always with full stop, add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks all. All of them are useful. I didn't know that "a space" was thousand separator for French. The question is: how can I write e.g. the dbvalue 123456   like 123.456 and 123,456  I mean can someone give a code example?  I see cultureinfo.invariantculture but can someone give a sample?